# Every infinite recursive set has a recursively enumerable subset which is not recursive.

Tags: logic, computability

Is the above statement true? If so, how do I go about proving it?

Another thing: Given two recursively enumerable sets $Q_1$,$Q_2$, I want to prove that $Q_1\backslash Q_2$ isn't necessarily recursively enumerable.
I assume that for this I need the complement of $Q_2$ to be not recursively enumerable, but could someone give a concrete example/way of of constructing a set such that I can prove my claim.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Quibble: you want to restrict attention to **infinite** recursive sets, otherwise e.g. $\{17\}$ is a counterexample. :P

Comment: @RobArthan: You're totally right, I mixed up recursive and r.e.

Comment: @see: it is customary jargon to talk about r.e. and recursive *languages* rather than sets when modelling computation with Turing machines, because Turing machines take as their input finite strings of symbols. I imagine you are working with partial recursive functions on the natural numbers. The two approaches are equivalent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Μ-recursive_function).

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first question: you can assume w.l.o.g. that the recursive set is $\Bbb{N}$ (and the question needs qualifying: finite sets are recursive sets that have no non-recursive subsets, so the recursive set has to be infinite).

Hint for the second question: you can get a counter-example in which $Q_1 = \Bbb{N}$.

Both questions reduce to finding an r.e. subset of $\Bbb{N}$ that is not recursive.

If you need more details, then you need to provide some more information about what you've tried so we can know what techniques you are familiar with.

Comment: How does your first hint work?  Isn't the empty set recursive?

Comment: @cardboard_box: yes, thanks, good point. The first question requires the recursive set to be infinite. I've pointed this out in my answer.

Comment: @cardboard_box: I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Got the second one thanks to your hint. Regarding the first question: I clarified the title.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Well I know that an infinite subset of the natural numbers has uncountably many subsets, but of those only countably many can be recursive or recursively enumerable. Also by w.l.o.g. you mean using a bijection between the (number-)space $\mathbb{N}^k$ I'm in and the natural numbers?

Comment: The reason you need the recursive set to be infinite is that every finite set is recursive. (You are right that an argument about the uncountability of $\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{N})$ is not useful here.) By "w.l.o.g." I meant that given an inifinite recursive set $X$, there is an effective bijection between $\Bbb{N}$ and $X$. If you can produce a non-r.e. subset of $\Bbb{N}$, then its image under that bijection is a non-r.e. subset of $X$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I could use a recursive, injective function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ which isn't strictly monotonically increasing and consider its image (which has to be infinite). It won't be recursive, but recursively enumerable. But for this I need said function.

Comment: Try a function that enumerates Indices of partial recursive functions that are defined at $0$ or a function that enumerates the Goedel numbers of sentences provable in PA.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Hm I didn't consider that I would also have to prove that my set isn't the image of another, possibly strictly monotonically increasing recursive function in my last comment. I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. Seems a bit too advanced for me at the moment.

Comment: I was trying to jog your memory with examples of r.e. sets that are not recursive that you might have studied already. If you don't know how to prove that such sets exist, then you won't be able to prove either of the results you are asking about.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Alright then. Thank you anyway.